# how to remove horizontal scroll in a fixed width?

Tags: html, media-queries

I am using media query to design responsive website. By default screen doesn't have any horizontal scroll when the size of the screen changes to 320px also the size of all element is 320px but horizontal scroll is added. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some code?

To simply remove scroll you can use body{overflow-x:hidden;} but if your responsive css code is correct, there shouldn't be any horizontal scrolling anyway.

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden` might do what you want. However, this "removes" everything that does not fit into the container.

Comment: Yea, also if the scroll shouldn't appear, you should find what causes it and fix that code, not just use overflow-x:hidden patch. But in order for us to help you, pls provide code.

Comment: thank you I check all code but I did not found anything when i check it in firebug the body tag dont get whole the page I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-x: hidden` to "cut off" everything that does not fit into the container and remove the scrollbar.

You should check what causes the problem. That might be the margin / padding / border of the container or of any superior containers.

Comment: thank you so much but I used it but it was not useful for me because i can see some part of page.